# How to make an import script from XML to SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I would like to know how to import the data from an XML File into a table in SQL. The table which I would like to import the data into looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTINFORMATION
(EAN      INT,
 Brand    VARCHAR(30),
 Model    VARCHAR(30),
 Size     VARCHAR(5),
 Price    INT,
 Currency VARCHAR(3)
);
```

So I have a XML file with a lot of this data and some other data, but i only want to import the data from EAN, Brand, Model, Size, Price and Currency. But how do I make an import script to do this?

sorry if I can't show the whole XML data, since it is confidential. But it looks like this:

```
<Lines>
  <Line>
    <LineNo></LineNo>
    <EANNo></EANNo>
    <CustomerItemNo />
    <ItemNo></ItemNo>
    <Description></Description>
    <Description2></Description2>
    <GrossWeight></GrossWeight>
    <NetWeight></NetWeight>
    <UnitVolume></UnitVolume>
    <UnitofMeasure></UnitofMeasure>
    <UnitPrice></UnitPrice>
    <EarliestDeliveryDate></EarliestDeliveryDate>
    <LatestDeliveryDate></LatestDeliveryDate>
    <StyleNo></StyleNo>
    <Style></Style>
    <ColourNo></ColourNo>
    <Colour></Colour>
    <SizeNo></SizeNo>
    <Size></Size>
    <MinimumQuantity></MinimumQuantity>
    <BrandCode></BrandCode>
    <BrandName></BrandName>
    <SeasonCode></SeasonCode>
    <RetailPrice></RetailPrice>
    <LineDiscountPct></LineDiscountPct>
    <NetUnitPrice></NetUnitPrice>
    <SupplierArticleGroup></SupplierArticleGroup>
    <Material />
    <PLUText />
    <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
    <SeasonText></SeasonText>
    <Tariffno></Tariffno>
    <SerialNumber />
    <Width></Width>
    <Height></Height>
    <Deph></Deph>
    <FreeText />
    <References />
  </Line>
  <Line>
```

Comment: please tag the RDBMS you're using

Comment: Thanks man, I tagged the Microsoft SSMS

Comment: Load the file using BULK load https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/load-xml-data into temporary table and parse it with  XML type methods

Comment: took me about 3 seconds to google it: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/

Comment: @NikolaiLindholm pls. show your XML data from which we could suggest you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I also found this article before I made the post, but needed some extra help.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I put it in the question, without data in.

Comment: So I followed the tutorial https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/ 
But i have a problem finding the root in my XML-file, anyone can help me?

Comment: @NikolaiLindholm just check with your XML, the root element present or not ? if present then wht name you have define.

Comment: your current xml doesn't have root element.

Comment: Hmm this is just a "plug out" from the XML-file, but I though every XML-file had a root? @YogeshSharma

Comment: No, but it is recommend to use <XML> as root element.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things here...

1. Import the XML file to a temporary (or permanent) table using OPENROWSET, converting the column to an XML data type.
2. Shred the XML datatype using either OPENXML or XQUERY

There is a very good post on this [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/)

Comment: When I use OPENROWSET, my SSMS can't open the XML File, I get the error :
Unable to show XML. The following error happened:
Unexpected end of file has occurred. the following elements are not closed color, line, lines, body, document. line 1, position 2097154.

One solution is to increase the number of characters retrieved from the server for XML data. TO chance this setting, on the tools menu, click options.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Nikolai Lindholm,

pls. check below small piece of code which could help you to import xml data.

```
CREATE PROC DEMO @XMLDATA XML
AS
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @Hdoc INT;
         EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT
              @Hdoc OUTPUT,
              @XMLDATA;
         INSERT INTO PRODUCTINFORMATION
                SELECT XML.EAN,
                       XML.Brand,
                       XML.Model,
                       XML.Size,
                       XML.Price,
                       XML.Currency
                FROM OPENXML(@Hdoc, '/XML/Line', 2) WITH(EAN INT, Brand VARCHAR(30), Model VARCHAR(30), Size VARCHAR(5), Price INT, Currency VARCHAR(3)) XML;
     END;
```

Comment: Hey Yogesh, I will try to run the code. But when the values EAN, Brand, Model, Size, Price and Currency are some I have defined and they have another name in the XML, can I still run the code, or do i have to do something else?

Comment: Your XML field name (EAN, Brand, etc) would be same name in future, otherwise it will insert NULL value in table.  or you could change the field name according your xml field name.